# valgrind gives invalid read of size 1

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

I have gone through several similarly asked questions regarding the same error code, most concern with passing invalid pointer addresses in return. However, this looks not to be the case here as my program correctly works with whatever address is passed in return.

**format_string:**

```
static char *format_string(char *string)
{
    int i;

    if (string == NULL) {
        return string;
    }
    string[0] = (char)toupper((int)string[0]);

    111->for (i = 1; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (!isalpha(string[i-1])) {
            string[i] = (char)toupper((int)string[i]);
        } else {
            string[i] = (char)tolower((int)string[i]);
        }
        if (string[i] == '/' || string[i] == '\\') {
        string[i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    /* Remove End of string White Spaces */
    while (string[--i]==' '); string[++i]='\0';

    return string;
}
```

**metadata_extract:**

```
static int metadata_extract(const char *filename, struct kw_metadata *s)
{
    char *memchar = NULL;
    s->obj = NULL;
    s->do_cleanup = &do_on_cleanup;
    if (!is_of_type(filename)) {        
        return KW_ERROR;
    }

    TagLib_File* file = taglib_file_new(filename); 
    TagLib_Tag* tag = taglib_file_tag(file);

    s->type = strdup("Audio");
    s->tagc = 4;
    s->tagtype = (char **)malloc(4 * sizeof(char *));
    s->tagv = (char **)malloc(4 * sizeof(char *));

    memchar = strdup("title");
    s->tagtype[0] = memchar;
    memchar = strdup("artist");
    s->tagtype[1] = memchar;
    memchar = strdup("album");
    s->tagtype[2] = memchar;
    memchar = strdup("genre");
    s->tagtype[3] = memchar;

    153->memchar = strdup(taglib_tag_title(tag));
    memchar = format_string(memchar);
    s->tagv[0] = memchar;
    memchar = strdup(taglib_tag_artist(tag));
    memchar  = format_string(memchar);
    s->tagv[1] = memchar;
    memchar = strdup(taglib_tag_album(tag));
    160->memchar = format_string(memchar);
    s->tagv[2] = memchar;
    memchar = strdup(taglib_tag_genre(tag));
    memchar = format_string(memchar);
    s->tagv[3] = memchar;

    s->obj = file;
    s->do_init = &do_on_init;
    s->do_cleanup = &do_on_cleanup;

    taglib_tag_free_strings();
    taglib_file_free(file);

    return KW_SUCCESS;
}
```

**valgrind:**

```
==16769== Invalid read of size 1
==16769==    at 0x5317605: format_string (plugin_taglib.c:111)
==16769==    by 0x531781F: metadata_extract (plugin_taglib.c:160)
==16769==    by 0x405EB3: metadata_extract (metadata_extract.c:36)
==16769==    by 0x403351: add_metadata_file (dbbasic.c:221)
==16769==    by 0x4032D5: add_file (dbbasic.c:174)
==16769==    by 0x406485: import_semantics (import.c:97)
==16769==    by 0x406440: import_semantics (import.c:92)
==16769==    by 0x4065AC: import (import.c:127)
==16769==    by 0x401916: main (kwest_main.c:87)
==16769==  Address 0x6f4ce11 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==16769==    at 0x4C2B3F8: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16769==    by 0x57A6D71: strdup (strdup.c:43)
==16769==    by 0x531780F: metadata_extract (plugin_taglib.c:159)
==16769==    by 0x405EB3: metadata_extract (metadata_extract.c:36)
==16769==    by 0x403351: add_metadata_file (dbbasic.c:221)
==16769==    by 0x4032D5: add_file (dbbasic.c:174)
==16769==    by 0x406485: import_semantics (import.c:97)
==16769==    by 0x406440: import_semantics (import.c:92)
==16769==    by 0x4065AC: import (import.c:127)
==16769==    by 0x401916: main (kwest_main.c:87)
```

Comment: Why the `const` in the declaration of `format_string`?  It's a blatant lie.

Comment: because I have to pass the function address and it expects it in that format :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (string[i-1]) {
```

you're reading `string[-1]`, which usually is an invalid read of size 1.

Presumably you meant

```
for(i = 1; ...
```

---

After edit:

Before the loop, you should check that the string has at least one character before it ends,

```
if (string[0] == 0) return string;
```

(best done before `string[0] = (char)toupper((int)string[0]);` even). The message

> Address 0x6f4ce11 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd

tells you that one of your `strdup`ed strings was empty (block of size 1 means only space for the 0-terminator was allocated).

When you mark off trailing spaces,

```
while (string[--i]==' '); string[++i]='\0';
```

you don't check whether the index is valid, if the entire string consisted of spaces, you read at least `string[-1]`, you should check that:

```
while(i-- > 0 && string[i] == ' ');
string[++i] = 0;
```

Comment: Updated. Off hand, I don't see more problems in `format_string`.

Comment: yes, I overlooked the empty strings possibility! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try validating with **if (NULL != memchar)** before actually using the variable; otherwise `strdup` and functions alike give unpredictable results.